# plot ECG signal in python from a .wav file

Tags: python, signal-processing

I plotted a an ECG signal form a [.dat file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fOTN2nKX2E5vbcqnl4K2CAMhcKV-d_S1) using this code :

```
import wfdb 
record = wfdb.rdsamp('mitdb/100', sampto=3000)
annotation = wfdb.rdann('mitdb/100', 'atr', sampto=3000)
print(type(record))
wfdb.plotrec(record, 
         title='Record 100 from MIT-BIH Arrhythmia Database .dat form',
         timeunits = 'seconds', figsize = (10,4), ecggrids = 'all')
```

and I got the following plot :

ecg plot out of a .dat file

[image]

Then i tried to plot the same signal out of a [.wav file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A-DO712X2xxoMS7LW6mrE5JGhVhi_yYe) using this python code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import wave


spf = wave.open('sig100.wav','r')

#Extract Raw Audio from Wav File
signal = spf.readframes(-1)
signal = np.fromstring(signal, 'Int16')
fs = spf.getframerate()

#If Stereo
if spf.getnchannels() == 2:
    print ('Just mono files 11')



Time=np.linspace(0, len(signal)/fs, num=len(signal))
print(Time)

plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Record 100 from MIT-BIH Arrhythmia Database .wav form')
plt.plot(Time,signal)
plt.show()
```

ang I got the following result :

ecg plot out of .wav file

[image]

how can I get a plot similar to the first one out of a .wav file and why did I get a different result first place

Comment: Why are you hiding the images?

Comment: i did not hid them didn't know what was wrong

Comment: You could share the .dat and the .wav.

Comment: both files are now available

Comment: You just need to "zoom in" by changing the x-axis bounds (e.g. plot only 0-10 seconds).